# c# Dragging PictureBox inside Panel

Tags: c#, limit, draggable, drag, restrict

I have a PictureBox1 draggable with this code:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }
    }

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Left + pictureBox1.Width> panel1.Width)
                pictureBox1.Left += (e.X - x);
        }
    }
```

But I can't get bound restrictions,
I just want move the Picture inside a Panel, like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggM3r.png)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int left = 0;
        if (pictureBox1.Left >= 0 && pictureBox1.Right <= panel1.Width)
            left = pictureBox1.Left + (e.X - x);

        left = Math.Min(panel1.Width - pictureBox1.Width , left);
        left = Math.Max(0, left);
        pictureBox1.Left = left;
    }
}
```

Comment: It Works Thanks.!, but pictureBox1 is blinking in boundaries of panel :(
Please any suggestion?

Comment: That's because we are assigning it twice. I edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, works fine.!!!
One day I hope having your knowledge about c#.   :)